# typo3 Bootstrap Package Subnavigation Left

Tags: typo3-9.x

I create a site based on Typo3 9.5.12 / Bootstrap Package 11.0.2.
The page tree looks like

```
Root > Sub1 > Sub1Sub1
Root > Sub1 > Sub1Sub2
Root > Sub1 > Sub1Sub3
Root > Sub2
Root > Sub3
```

I want to create a subnavigation menu for *Sub1* so I create a page Root > Sub1 > Nav and I select *Subnavigation Left*.

I expected the navigation menu on this page to display *Sub1Sub1*, *Sub1Sub2* and *Sub1Sub3*.

Instead, it displays the whole page tree.

I tried this in the official introduction package and the *Subnavigation Left* page display the list of pages of the current level in most cases.

How does *Subnavigation Left* (and *Subnavigation Right*, for that matter) decide the entry point of the menu? Can this be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use another menuprocessor to define your additional menu in typoscript:

```
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        :
        dataProcessing {
            :

            50 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            50 {
                levels = 2
                entryLevel = 2
                expandAll = 1
                includeSpacer = 1
                as = menuLevel3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a menu structure for level 3 and level 4 pages you can use in your FLUID templates.

Make the configuration as you need it.
`levels` = how many levels should there in the menu data
`entryLevel` = starting level, as the first two levels are included in your main menu you can start at level 2
`expandAll` = include all sublevels (`1`) or just the active page tree (`0`), only important with further page levels
`includeSpacer` = whether spacer pages are included in the data
`as` = the name of your FLUID variable